# Disable routing to a specific page directly in Gatsby.js

Tags: reactjs, routes, gatsby

I have success page which has to be displayed when the form is submitted in Gatsby. But the user can directly visit /success page. Is there any way to prevent it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do this. [One is outlined here by Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/building-apps-with-gatsby/#client-only-routes--user-authentication) and involves creating a client-only route (that is, Gatsby won't have React render it server-side, but will route to your component on the client/browser). That looks something like this:

```
exports.onCreatePage = async ({ page, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  // page.matchPath is a special key that's used for matching pages
  // only on the client.
  if (page.path.match(/^\/app/)) {
    page.matchPath = "/app/*"

    // Update the page.
    createPage(page)
  }
}
```

A route I've taken to do this, especially when it's not a particularly sensitive page, is to render the page, but check for some condition on render and use `navigate` if the condition isn't satisfied.

For example, if you stored `formSubmitted` in `AppContext`, you could do something like this:

```
import React, { useContext } from "react"
import { navigate } from "gatsby"

const SuccessPage = () => {
  const { formSubmitted } = useContext(AppContext)
  return formSubmitted ? <div>Thanks!</div> : navigate("/contact", { replace: true })
}
```